# late static binding failed on magic method

Tags: php

```
class parents {

public function __call( $name , $arguments )    {
    var_dump( __CLASS__ );
}

public function test () {
    var_dump( __CLASS__ );
}
}



class child extends parents{

public function __call( $name , $arguments )    {
    var_dump( __CLASS__ );
}

public function test () {
    var_dump( __CLASS__ );
}

public function lateStaticTest ()   {
    parent::test();
    parent::call();

    $this->test();
    $this->call();
}

}


$child = new child();
$child->lateStaticTest();
```

outputs
string 'parents' (length=7)
string 'child' (length=5)
string 'child' (length=5)
string 'child' (length=5)

expected outputs
string 'parents' (length=7)
string 'parents' (length=5)
string 'child' (length=5)
string 'child' (length=5)

it seems that late static binding fail on calling magic method from parrent class, or i miss something ?

thanks :D

Comment: I might be missing something here, but "what late static binding"?

Comment: Since the parent doesn't have a method `call`, I'd say the result of `parent::call()` is not clearly defined. In this case it seems to trigger `child::__call` first.

Comment: yeah, i think i misunderstood "what late static binding", i assume whit the keyword "parent" will always call parent class method.

Answer (score 1):

**This is entirely by design.**

`parent::call()` invokes `parent::call()`. From [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php):

> More precisely, **late static bindings work by storing the class named in the last "non-forwarding call"**. In case of static method calls, this is the class explicitly named (usually the one on the left of the `::` operator); in case of non static method calls, it is the class of the object. **A "forwarding call" is a static one that is introduced by `self::`, `parent::`, `static::`, or, if going up in the class hierarchy, `forward_static_call()`.**

Your call uses `parent::`, so there is no way you can "use" late static bindings here.

`$this->call()` is the correct way to achieve polymorphism in this case.

Comment: yeah, i think i misunderstood "what late static binding", i've doing some test, if someoen have same problem, put simply want to acces __call from parent where is overridden in child can simply use parent::__call :D